# How to compile a java source file which is encoded as "UTF-8"?

Tags: java, unicode, compiler-errors, javac

I saved my Java source file specifying it's encoding type as UTF-8 (using Notepad, by default Notepad's encoding type is ANSI) and then I tried to compile it using:

```
javac -encoding "UTF-8" One.java
```

but it gave an error message"

```
One.java:1: illegal character: \65279

?public class One {

^
1 error
```

Is there any other way, I can compile this?

Here is the source:

```
public class One {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println("HI");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your file *is* being read as UTF-8, otherwise a character with value "65279" could never appear. `javac` expects your source code to be in the platform default encoding, according to [the `javac` documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> If **-encoding** is not specified, the platform default converter is used.

Decimal 65279 is hex FEFF, which is the [Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  It's unnecessary in UTF-8, because UTF-8 is always encoded as an octet stream and doesn't have endianness issues.

Notepad likes to stick in BOMs even when they're not necessary, but some programs don't like finding them.  As others have pointed out, Notepad is not a very good text editor.  Switching to a different text editor will almost certainly solve your problem.

Comment: +1: here's the alternative: use notepad++, editplus or consorts or, only if you've a good grasp on coding/building/running java at commandline, an IDE like Eclipse

Comment: Notepad is decent for telling if a file *is* UTF-8 (or UTF-16) but this issue is a pretty serious one IMHO and a lot of people get tripped up by it.

Comment: Notepad sticks a BOM in there so that later on it (or anything else that understand BOMs) can figure out that the file is most likely UTF-8.

Comment: That saved my day! From now on, only Notepad++ in my computer.

Comment: @JohanBoulé: What are you talking about? The answer doesn't even *mention* Notepad++, it's only mentioned in the comments. When the answer says "Notepad" it's referring to the Windows built-in application "Notepad", not Notepad++.

Answer (score 20):

Open the file in Notepad++ and select Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 14):

This isn't a problem with your text editor, it's a problem with javac !
The Unicode spec says BOM is optionnal in UTF-8, it doesn't say it's forbidden !
If a BOM can be there, then javac HAS to handle it, but it doesn't. Actually, using the BOM in UTF-8 files IS useful to distinguish an ANSI-coded file from an Unicode-coded file.

The proposed solution of removing the BOM is only a workaround and not the proper solution.

This bug report indicates that this "problem" will never be fixed : https://web.archive.org/web/20160506002035/http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4508058

Since this thread is in the top 2 google results for the "javac BOM" search, I'm leaving this here for future readers.

Comment: The general Java change for all UTF-8 streams was reverted due to [JDK-6378911](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6378911) impacting code that expects to read the BOM. It would need to be fixed in `javac` itself.

Answer (score 9):

Try `javac -encoding UTF8 One.java`

Without the quotes and it's UTF8, no dash.

[See this forum thread for more links](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=560900)

Comment: Problem is the BOM which notepad adds and which javac doesn't need

Answer (score 6):

See Below
For example we can discuss with an Program (Telugu words)

**Program (UnicodeEx.java)**

```
class UnicodeEx {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        double ఎత్తు = 10;  
        double వెడల్పు = 25;   
        double దీర్ఘ_చతురస్ర_వైశాల్యం;  
        System.out.println("The Value of Height = "+ఎత్తు+" and Width = "+వెడల్పు+"\n");  
        దీర్ఘ_చతురస్ర_వైశాల్యం = ఎత్తు * వెడల్పు;  
        System.out.println("Area of Rectangle = "+దీర్ఘ_చతురస్ర_వైశాల్యం);  
    }  
}
```

This is the Program while saving as "UnicodeEx.java" and change Encoding to "unicode"

****How to Compile****

> javac -encoding "unicode" UnicodeEx.java

**How to Execute**

> java UnicodeEx

The Value of Height = 10.0 and Width = 25.0

Area of Rectangle = 250.0

Comment: I had trouble with UTF-8 encoded source files with a UTF-8 BOM.  Converting to UTF-16 LE (with corresponding BOM) and adding -encoding unicode to the javac command line compiled fine.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very old thread, but I was experiencing a similar problem with PHP instead of Java and Google took me here. I was writing PHP on Notepad++ (not plain Notepad) and noticed that an extra white line appeared every time I called an include file. Firebug showed that there was a 65279 character in those extra lines.

Actually both the main PHP file and the included files were encoded in UTF-8. However, Notepad++ has also an option to encode as "UTF-8 without BOM". This solved my problem.

Bottom line: UTF-8 encoding inserts here and there this extra BOM character unless you instruct your editor to use UTF8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here, even edited in Notepad.  Moral of the story is, don't use Notepad.  There's likely a unprintable character in there that Notepad is either inserting or happily hiding from you.

Comment: The BOM (Byte Order Mark) is a non-printable character, which means it is meant to be hidden from the editing window. Any good text editor should however be aware of the presence of this mark and honor whatever information it contains. Using a hexadecimal/binary editor show allow you to check how the BOM is constructed. The BOM only causes problems with badly written or non-unicode-compliant tools, and any tool which breaks in the presence of a BOM should be fixed ASAP (it's 2015 for god's sake ...!). Here's more info about the BOM : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: But I totally agree with the whole "not using Notepad" idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To solve it opened the file in a hex editor and found three "invisible" bytes at the beginning of the file. I removed them, and compilation worked.

Comment: Those "three invisible bytes" are what is called the BOM (Byte Order Mark) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 0):

- Open your file with WordPad or any other editor except Notepad.
- Select Save As type as Text Document - MS-DOS Format
- Reopen the Project

Comment: That is terrible advice… What would happen to the Unicode characters that are already in the document?

Answer (score 0):

**To extend the existing answers with a solution for Linux users**:

To remove the BOM on all `.java` files at once, go to your source directory and execute

`find -iregex '.*\.java' -type f -print0  | xargs -0 dos2unix`

Requires `find`, `xargs` and `dos2unix` to be installed, which should be included in most distributions. The first statement finds all `.java` files in the current directory recursively, the second one converts each of them with the `dos2unix` tool, which is intended to convert line endings but also removes the BOM.

The line endings conversion should have no effect as it should already be in Linux `\n` format on Linux if you configure your version control correctly but be warned that it does that as well in case you have one of those rare cases where that is not intended.

Answer (score 0):

In the Intellij Idea(Settings>Editor>File Encodings), the project encoding was "windows-1256". So I used the following code to convert static strings to utf8

```
protected String persianString(String persianStirng) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return new String(persianStirng.getBytes("windows-1256"), "UTF-8");
}
```

Now It is OK!
Depending on the file encoding you should change "windows-1256" to a proper one