# How do I add multiple java classes into a Mono for Android project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

I have been working on this [google map sample](https://github.com/mono/monodroid-samples/tree/master/GoogleMaps) using the Mono for Android evaluation version. I now what to add overlays which requires adding a second java class. When i try to add a new java class, even a simple empty class, to either the bottom of the existing .java file, or a new .java file ([with a build action of AndroidJavaSource](http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Build_Process)), I get an error packaging the project.

Help? What am I missing? [Is there a limitation to the evaluation version of Mono for Android that isn't documented?](http://android.xamarin.com/DownloadTrial) Do I need to register the new class somewhere?

Edit:

The error is: "illegal character: \65279"

Comment: +1 Thanks for the prompt. I was so het up that I couldn't see an error that I forgot to look for it! The only way I could get the error was to go to Tools -> Options -> Mono for Android and check "Adb logging" which writes a log to the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1726174/674717), the issue is a "bad" (in javac.exe's point of view) byte order mark in file. The file .java was created by from a text file created via Visual Studio.

I made a copy the .java file that I source from the sample and made the necessary alterations and it worked. TA DA!