# Printing Hindi characters as string in java results in error

Tags: java

I print hindi characters as string in java and I'm getting an error. I save the java file in notepad uing UTF-8.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String s = "साहिलसाहिल";

        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

After compilation, I get 2 errors of illegal character. Why so?

Comment: It generally should compile (and it does, for me). Can you check the encoding once?

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?  Are you compiling on Windows or Linux or something else?

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726174/how-to-compile-a-java-source-file-which-is-encoded-as-utf-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the appropriate encoding :

```
javac -encoding utf8 MainClass.java
```

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling like this:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 MainClass.java
```

Make sure that you use the correct name for the encoding too.

If this fails, it is likely that the problem that the Notepad is adding a BOM at the front, and that is confusing the java compiler.  If that is your problem, you should stop using Notepad for editing UTF-8 files.  Use a decent text editor that doesn't add a BOM to UTF-8 files.

Answer (score 1):

try it with

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 MainClass.java`

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the source file in UTF-8 format (easy to do it using Notepad++ or Eclipse IDE) and then compile with the `-encoding` switch to `javac`.

```
javac -encoding utf8 MainClass.java
```