# Illegal Character on Jenkins Server

Tags: java, jenkins, utf, byte-order-mark

I had now several Problems with my Jenkins Build Server and i dont know where they come from...
I'm getting this error message:

```
illegal character: \65279
```

which seems like to be UTF16-BOM.
When i open the corresponding file with a HEX Editor, i cant see a `FE FF` mark at the beginning, or somewhere else in the code.
Also file does not say anything about BOM:

```
TransactionFunctionImpl.java: UTF-8 Unicode Java program text
```

Whats going on there?

Another question is: why cant my jenkins server build bom files, when my eclipse does it?

Comment: Where are you seeing this error message? When doing what?

Comment: when trying to build the project. I'm getting this error from javac

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles):

> Note: the JDK 1.6 javac compiler will not compile a UTF-8 source file
>   starting with a byte order mark, failing with the error illegal
>   character: \65279.

So presumably the JDK version differs between your desktop and your Jenkins server.

The best solution would be to remove the redundant BOM from your source, as suggested [in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1726174/234938).

Comment: its borh the same... also very curious: the file isnt a BOM file!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this using Samsung's S pen Sdk example source on Linux.

Copy the text of the program and paste it into an entirely new file. Works for me.