# Compiling (javac) a UTF8 encoded Java source code with a BOM

Tags: utf-8, javac, byte-order-mark

Hello and thank you for reading my post.

My problem is the following: I want to compile a Java source file with "javac" with this file being UTF-8 encoded with a BOM (the OS is WinXP).

Below is what I do:

1) Create a file with "Notepad" and choose the UTF-8 encoding

```
dos> notepad Test.java
"File -> Save as..."
File name   : Test.java
Save as type: All Files
Encoding    : UTF-8
Save
```

2) Create a Java class in that file and saved the file like in 1)

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("This is a test.");
    }
}
```

3) Visualize the hexadecimal version of the file (first line)

```
dos> xxd Test.java | head -1
0000000: efbb bf70 7562 6c69 6320 636c 6173 7320  ...public class
```

Note:
**ef bb bf** is the UTF-8 encoded BOM (the UTF-16 encoded BOM being **FE FF**).

4) Try to compile this code with "javac"

```
dos> javac -encoding utf8 Test.java
Test.java:1: illegal character: \65279
?public class Test
^
1 error
```

Note: **65279** is the decimal version of the BOM.

My question is the following: how can I make this compiling work with:

- keeping it UTF-8 encoded
- and keeping the BOM?

Thank you for helping and best regards.

Léa

Comment: That’s right: you have to remove the BOM.  It has no business in UTF-8, so of course it is an error. This is a long-standing Microsoft bug. Never ever put a BOM in UTF-8!!!!!

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer.
I used "Notepad++" to encode the file as "UTF8 without BOM".
Compiling the code with "javac" now works.

Comment: @tchrist [The Unicode Standard (page 30)](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch02.pdf) allows for a BOM in UTF-8 so you have every right to put it there if you so wish. Why you'd want to is another story, but `javac` should handle it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile a java source file which is encoded as "UTF-8"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726174/how-to-compile-a-java-source-file-which-is-encoded-as-utf-8)

Answer (score 37):

Trim the BOM and then use `javac -encoding utf8 x.java`

Comment: This solved my javac compiling problem. But now Windows10 console still showing unknown characters like "???????????".

Comment: Afaiu, `chcp 65001` should help you with console.

Comment: Tried this also, issue not resolved. Open question marks "?????" converted into boxed question marks. Windows console still not recognizing text. Here that shows correct like: लोकसभा के चुनावी रण में सत्तारूढ़ भाजपा की ओर से सिर्फ नरेन्द्र मोदी ही दिखाई दे रहे हैं।

Comment: This is what I haven't been able to solve for at least 3 months. Thanks for the stackoverflow!

Answer (score 20):

This isn't a problem with your text editor, it's a problem with javac !
The Unicode spec says BOM is optionnal in UTF-8, it doesn't say it's forbidden !
If a BOM can be there, then javac HAS to handle it, but it doesn't. Actually, using the BOM in UTF-8 files IS useful to distinguish an ANSI-coded file from an Unicode-coded file.

The proposed solution of removing the BOM is only a workaround and not the proper solution.

This bug report indicates that this "problem" will never be fixed : https://web.archive.org/web/20160506002035/http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4508058

Since this thread is in the top 2 google results for the "javac BOM" search, I'm leaving this here for future readers.

Comment: Actually, the bug you reference has to do with the UTF-8 decoder; it has nothing to do with whether the *compiler* can be altered to detect and discard any BOM on a Java source file, which it can, and should.

Answer (score -1):

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043356/7050261
>
> Actually, using the BOM in UTF-8 files IS useful to distinguish an ANSI-coded file from an Unicode-coded file.

Actually

- BOM is not about distinguishing ANSI and Unicode. Do not use a
  feature on purpose it is not designed for.
- UTF-8 was designed to be backward-compatible with ANSI intentionally, so a lot of
  code written to process formatted text relied on
  0..127 bytes only (XML, JSON, etc.) should work correctly with UTF-8 encoded text without any modifications.

Comment: note: it is byte-level compatibility only, but char-level calculations became wrong when UTF-8 used in place of ANSI.

Comment: UTF-8 is only backward-compatible with _ASCII_ (7-bit range, `0x0 - 0x7F`), not also with _ANSI_ (an ASCII _extension_ that also defines characters in the 8-bit range, `0x80 - 0xFF`, and that range is _not_ compatible with UTF-8). Yes, a BOM in a UTF-8 file serves to distinguish it from an ANSI (or OEM, ....) file.