# how to update project configuration in command?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want update project configuration in command not ecplise.

I'm try 'mvn dependency:resolve', 'mvn versions:update-properties' etc..

but all build is fail.

Ecplise maven -> update Maven Project click and

command 'mvn package' that build success.

why happen this problem? and I want to know update project configuation pom.xml in command line.

Thank you.

Comment: "update project configuration" relates to files used by eclipse. since maven is not aware of an IDE I would assume there is no real command line version. There are some maven-ecplipse plugins around but eclipse is not really a fan of newly written .classpath / .project files. Why does the build fail on the command line? Does "mvn clean package" on the command line work (without eclipse doing something before that, close it to be safe)?

Comment: When project build (mvn package) that The console print 'illegal character: \65279' and 'class, interface, or enum expected'.
but On eclipse 'update Maven Project' click and again try the project build then build is success.
I think the project not update pom.xml so I want to 'update Maven Project' in command line

Comment: no you dont want that :) Be aware that eclipse uses its own compiler to enable some features required for an IDE. But once you use continuous integration you need to use the JDK compiler. So the error you are getting seems to be related to some encoding issue in a file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555504/illegal-character-65279-during-maven-compile-despite-being-set-to-utf-8 which seems to be a similar issue. Rather rely on the command line than on eclipse magic. You will not run your application in eclipse on production.

Comment: Are you using the same version of maven in Eclipse and in command line?