# Turkish character while writing to database (postgresql)

Tags: java, postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, turkish

I am working with Java and PostgreSQL on Windows . I have some words which include turkish characters like İ,ş,ö,ç etc.

In Java I assign words to a string and try to write it to the database. When I print it on java its encoding appears correct and all characters display correctly. However, while writing it to database the text appears to get mangled/scrambled.

I created my database with this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname ENCODING "UTF-8"
```

I tried to fix it by converting Turkish characters into the ISO-8859-1 encoding like (İ -> \u0130 , ş -> \u015F)

```
//\u0130leti\u015Fim = İletişim
title = \u0130leti\u015Fim
String mytitle = new String(title.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

And then I tried to write `mytitle` to database but it did not work.

Thanks for your advice.

SOLVED : I realized  that it could write turkish characters to database, but the problem was on the response. I added these lines before write to response.

```
String contentType= "text/html;charset=UTF-8";   
response.setContentType(contentType);
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

After adding this, it works now. I hope, i could explain cleanly.

Comment: Are your Java source files saved as UTF-8? Also, ISO-8859-1 is **not** things like `İ` -> `\u0130` , `ş` -> `\u015F`.

Comment: They are saved as UTF-8.

Comment: What's the connection's [`client_encoding`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-ENCODING)?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `title.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")`, you're promising the Java runtime that the characters in the string *can* be represented as ISO-8859-1 bytes, which is not actually true for either \u0130 or \u015f.
Therefore already the conversion to bytes will do something unspecified with your Turkish characters -- probably they will just be dropped.

Next, attempting to interpret whichever bytes you get out of it as UTF-8 even though they're really ISO-8859-1 is then guaranteed to make a complete mess of *everything* that wasn't ASCII to begin with.

(The repretoire of ISO-8859-1 happens to coincide exactly with the Unicode characters that can be written as \u00XX for some XX).

Comment: I changed my code to:
title = "İletişim";
mytitle = new String(title.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
And i also tried it on ubuntu, but it still cannot write turkish characters to database correct.

Comment: But what on earth are you trying do achieve by converting the string to bytes and back to a string again? _At best_ you will get the original string back, but possibly some of the Turkish characters that are _already_ in the string will get destroyed by that pointless exercise. There's no possible way string->bytes->string can do anything useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

With encoding issues you have several things to check:

- Whether your source file is in the encoding you expect it to be.
- How `client_encoding` is set
- What the database encoding is

In the case of Java, PgJDBC requires `client_encoding` to always be `UTF-8` and will choke if you set it to something else, so that's not going to be the issue. You've shown that your database is `UTF-8` too. So it seems likely that your Java sources aren't in the same encoding the Java compiler and runtime expect them to be in.

By default [`javac` will interpret your source code in the platform default encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726222/398670). If you've saved your sources in a different encoding, weird things will happen. Save your sources either:

- in the default encoding for your Windows platform;
- as Unicode ("UTF-16" or "UCS-2"); or
- As UTF-8 with a *Byte Order Mark (BOM)*. Many programs don't add a BOM for UTF-8.

Then recompile your program. If that doesn't help, you'll need to follow up with more detail, starting with what *exactly* "it did not work" means, output of `SELECT`ing the data you inserted with Java using `psql`, etc.

Comment: When i save it in UTF-16 or UCS-2 it gives errors. I also tried to save it with UTF-8 with a BOM, but there is no change, it still cannot write to database Turkish characters.
Moreover, i also tried it on Ubuntu, but it did not change.

Comment: @sinan "It gives errors". What errors, exactly? Update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the database like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE <db name> 
        WITH OWNER <owner user name>
    TEMPLATE template0 
    ENCODING 'UTF-8' 
    LC_COLLATE 'tr_TR.UTF-8' 
    LC_CTYPE = 'tr_TR.UTF-8';
```