# Java Convert special characters into Unicode

Tags: java

I am using a Special Character in Java, which is causing an issue when I compile with **UTF-8** encoding.  How can I deal with this problem?  Here is a code snapshot.

```
language = new SelectOption<String>("default", "Default/d�faut");
```

Here's one more thing: I also have to figure out how to convert it into Unicode.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Stanley javac -encoding utf8 x.java

Comment: So, what is the error?

Comment: hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726174/how-to-compile-a-java-source-file-which-is-encoded-as-utf-8) helps. Notepad issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the unicode number of the character you can escape it as follows:

```
language = new SelectOption<String>("default", "Default/d\u2202faut");
```

where 2202 is the unicode number

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@Ernesto Campohermoso** and **@pratZ** it works and [here](http://www.snible.org/java2/uni2java.html) i found a link to convert Special Character to unicode  .

Like Unicode of this � is  **\uFFFD** which we can use in Java Class.

Comment: You're welcome, but instead of put an answer you can put a comment like this.

Answer (score 0):

If the source file in UTF-8 compile it as `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...` and there will be no problem.

To convert the source file to Unicode-encoded use `native2ascii` util from JDK http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html