# Why is String One = "Øzil" not a statement?

Tags: java, utf-8

Here is my little example code:

```
String legend = "Øzil";
if (legend.equals("Øzil")) {
    System.out.println("You should have bought him Moyes");
}
```

Whenever I try to compile this code I get this error message: **error: Not a Statement*** *String legend = Øzil"*

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in your code, a missing parenthesis at the end of the `if` statement...

Comment: @SteveP. Maybe it's a typo only in the question and not in his real code? He stated this in one of his comments.

Comment: THERE'S NOTHING WRONG WITH CODE YOU POSTED!

Comment: Please provide more context around these statements. The code provided will compile just fine. OS/Java Version/Command being used to compile would help as well.

Comment: @SteveP. Yes, the code may be fine, but why try to force OP to ask a question he clearly says is not relevant?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi I did not see that it was not relevant until he freaked out at me for no reason...

Comment: @SteveP. Yes, but he edited his question specifically to address the typo. It's best to just not touch syntax errors.

Comment: Could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726174/how-to-compile-a-java-source-file-which-is-encoded-as-utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed  `)` in the end of if statement

```
  if (legend.equals("Øzil") {
                          ^_____see here
```

Comment: It's a typo only in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the funny character you are using, you should find its ASCII code and use it instead.

EDIT: ooops now I see I got it wrong :)

Comment: You didn't get it wrong. I made a typo in the code I entered here, but not in the real code.

Comment: Java fully supports "funny characters" a.k.a. Unicode. Provided you use UTF-8 as source encoding, this is valid java: `String 傳說 = "Øzil";`

Comment: Thank you for the ONLY good answer so far. How do I use UTF-8 as source encoding?

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
         String legend = "Øzil";

         if (legend.equals("Øzil")) {
                 System.out.println("You should have bought him Moyes");
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add end bracket `)` to the if condition:

From

```
if (legend.equals("Øzil") {
```

to

```
if (legend.equals("Øzil")) {
```