# Spring annotations messages encoding

Tags: java, spring, encoding, utf-8, spring-annotations

How do I configure SpringMVC's annotation messages encoding? 
For example, I annotated a field of the form to be validated like this:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "ъ")
```

But when the error occurs, it is encoded in a wrong charset.
Encoding filter in web.xml is enabled and *.java files are UTF-8.
Tomcat's Connector in server.xml is configured to deal with UTF-8.

Comment: Java files are in UTF8, but have you configured the compiler to make it read Java files as UTF8? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726174/how-to-compile-a-java-source-file-which-is-encoded-as-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

If you know the original charset, you can try to convert the original string to UTF. For example:

```
public static String convertFromISO88591ToUTF8( String original )
{
    String converted = original;
    try
    {
        byte[] iso88591Bytes = original.getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" );
        converted = new String( iso88591Bytes, "UTF8" );
    }
    catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return converted;
}
```

Actually, I've been using this same method (without changes) on the back-end even regardless the encoding on the front-end and it has been working fine. However, I didn't make a systematic test for all encoding types.

I hope it helps.