# Compilation failure in maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I don't know why and already read many articles about this. But I set every part related the setting java version to 1.7.

But It still occurs the error

```
    [WARNING] The requested profile "anyframe" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project faro-jpa: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/admin/module/workgroupmgn/service/impl/WorkgroupMgnServiceImpl.java:[1,1] illegal character: \65279
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/admin/module/workgroupmgn/service/impl/WorkgroupMgnServiceImpl.java:[1,10] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/admin/module/logmgn/dao/impl/LogMgnDaoImpl.java:[1,1] illegal character: \65279
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/admin/module/logmgn/dao/impl/LogMgnDaoImpl.java:[1,10] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/admin/module/language/dao/impl/LanguageMgnDaoImpl.java:[1,1] illegal character: \65279
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/admin/module/language/dao/impl/LanguageMgnDaoImpl.java:[7,9] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/admin/module/language/service/impl/LanguageMgnServiceImpl.java:[1,1] illegal character: \65279
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/admin/module/language/service/impl/LanguageMgnServiceImpl.java:[7,9] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/common/session/FaroUserSessionHolder.java:[1,1] illegal character: \65279
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/common/session/FaroUserSessionHolder.java:[7,9] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/common/util/file/vo/NameMappingVo.java:[1,1] illegal character: \65279
[ERROR] /D:/workspace/camel/faro-jpa/src/main/java/com/sds/redca/hub/common/util/file/vo/NameMappingVo.java:[1,10] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project faro-jpa: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
```

Here is my maven log

```
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T22:51:42+09:00)
Maven home: D:\dev\ide\apache-maven-3.2.2
Java version: 1.8.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
Default locale: ko_KR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
```

And I set the jre System library of this project to java 7.

**UPDATE**

I added the most related part of pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <!-- <file>${system.score.path}/querydsl-apt-3.4.3.jar</file> -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                        <!-- <systemPath>${system.score.path}/querydsl-apt-3.4.3.jar</systemPath> -->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you show more information about your pom file?

Comment: Thanks.  @Rodolfo Which part of pom file want me to add? :D

Comment: Did you try mvn clean??

Comment: @IkerAguayo of course!! I kept running with mvn clean install

Comment: Ok. And did you try to set a version to maven-compiler-plugin. Try with version 3.x and then with 2.x if it does not work etc. To discard things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your pom has `sourceEncoding` property, although you put encoding configuration in `maven.complier.plugin`, I use to specify `sourceEncoding` into properties maven section.

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

Your maven error ouput complains about \65279 character, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726222/1283348) you can find what this character means and some explanation about it. Maybe you have to use another text editor.