# Compilation error using mvn compile: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: youtube-api

I got this error while trying to do something with the youtube DATA API, but I received an error listed on the title with tags[207:0].I have checked my curly braces and they seems to correspond to each other. What other problems it might be?

In this code, I am trying to extract the videos information like title, author, description, and number of views.

```
public class Search {

  /** Global instance properties filename. */
  private static String PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "youtube.properties";

  /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
  private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  /** Global instance of the max number of videos we want returned (50 = upper limit per page). */
  private static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED = 25;

  /** Global instance of Youtube object to make all API requests. */
  private static YouTube youtube;


  /**
   * Initializes YouTube object to search for videos on YouTube (Youtube.Search.List). The program
   * then prints the names and thumbnails of each of the videos (only first 50 videos).
   *
   * @param args command line args.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Read the developer key from youtube.properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
      InputStream in = Search.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
      properties.load(in);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("There was an error reading " + PROPERTIES_FILENAME + ": " + e.getCause()
          + " : " + e.getMessage());
      System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
      /*
       * The YouTube object is used to make all API requests. The last argument is required, but
       * because we don't need anything initialized when the HttpRequest is initialized, we override
       * the interface and provide a no-op function.
       */
      youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {}
      }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();

      // Get query term from user.
      String queryTerm = getInputQuery();

      YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");


      /*
       * It is important to set your developer key from the Google Developer Console for
       * non-authenticated requests (found under the API Access tab at this link:
       * code.google.com/apis/). This is good practice and increased your quota.
       */
      String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
      search.setKey(apiKey);
      search.setQ(queryTerm);
      /*
       * We are only searching for videos (not playlists or channels). If we were searching for
       * more, we would add them as a string like this: "video,playlist,channel".
       */
      search.setType("video");
      /*
       * This method reduces the info returned to only the fields we need and makes calls more
       * efficient.
       */
      search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/channelId,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
      search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);
      SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();


      List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
      List<String> videoIds = new ArrayList<String>();

      if (searchResultList != null) {
        prettyPrint(videoList.iterator(),queryTerm);


        // Merge video IDs
        for (SearchResult searchResult : searchResultList) {
            videoIds.add(searchResult.getId().getVideoId());
        }
        Joiner stringJoiner = Joiner.on(',');
        String videoId = stringJoiner.join(videoIds);

        // Call the YouTube Data API's youtube.videos.list method to
        // retrieve the resources that represent the specified videos.
        YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet, recordingDetails").setId(videoId);
        VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();
        List<Video> videoList = listResponse.getItems();

        if (videoList != null) {
                    prettyPrint(videoList.iterator(), queryTerm);
        }
      }
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
      System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
          + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /*
   * Returns a query term (String) from user via the terminal.
   */
  private static String getInputQuery() throws IOException {

    String inputQuery = "";

    System.out.print("Please enter a search term: ");
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    inputQuery = bReader.readLine();

    if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
      // If nothing is entered, defaults to "YouTube Developers Live."
      inputQuery = "YouTube Developers Live";
    }
    return inputQuery;

}

  /*
   * Prints out all SearchResults in the Iterator. Each printed line includes title, id, and
   * thumbnail.
   *
   * @param iteratorSearchResults Iterator of SearchResults to print
   *
   * @param query Search query (String)
   */
  private static void prettyPrint(Iterator<Video> iteratorVideoResults,String query) {

    System.out.println("\n=============================================================");
    System.out.println(
        "   First " + NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED + " videos for search on \"" + query + "\".");
    System.out.println("=============================================================\n");

    if (!iteratorVideoResults.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
    }

    while (iteratorVideoResults.hasNext()) {
      Video singleVideo = iteratorVideoResults.next();
      Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();

        System.out.println(" Video Id: " + singleVideo.getId());
        System.out.println(" Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
        System.out.println(" Description: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getDescription());
        System.out.println(" Author: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getChannelId());
        System.out.println(" Thumbnail: " + thumbnail.getUrl());
        System.out.println("View count: "+singleVideo.getStatistics().getViewCount());

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What code is on line 207? There aren't any line numbers in the code block.

Comment: There is no code on line 207,line 206 is the last line

Comment: @KhaiiJuInn checking [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12750070/4092887)1 [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32435233/4092887)2, it seems that the error is caused either by the encoding of the results or the `if there is extraneous text in the java file`. Try removing spaces-comments in your java file and edit the `prettyPrint` method for print only a few items. If you haven't tried yet, search `Compilation error using mvn compile: class, interface, or enum expected`. Good luck.