# Is there a way to add an encoding type to a word file using apache POI, so that Umlaute will be represented?

Tags: java, encoding, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to process some data with apache POI. I'm generating a word file, but since I'm german, I'm using Umlaute (ä,ö,ü), which aren't displayed correctly in the generated word file.
I **think**, a word file doesn't have an encoding set by default, but I'm not quite sure.

Is there a way to set an encoding style to the XWPFDocument object?

Help would be appreciated! Thank you very much!

Edit:

Sample code:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();
XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(0);
XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(0);
cell.setText("äüöß");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("OutputFile.docx"));
doc.write(fos);
doc.close();
```

Output is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLEOd.png

`System.getProperty("file.encoding");` returns `windows-1252`. Setting the Property to `UTF-8` didn't help.

Comment: Writing characters with umlauts (and other non-ASCII characters) to a Word (docx) document using Apache POI should be straightforward, with no need for any special handling for encodings. Can you edit your question, and add in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If you provide the relevant formatted code, that will help.

Comment: Sadly it isn't as straightforward as one would think. I've just edited the initial post with the code and an image of the output. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Try: `OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8")` and then `doc.write(osw)`

Comment: What value does this return: `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`

Comment: Hi Abra, I tried using a writer before, unfortunately doc.write() only accepts an outputstream as parameter. `System.getProperty("file.enconding")` returns `windows-1252`

Comment: @Habnix: have you verified that your Java file is compiled with the correct encoding? It's possible that your string constant doesn't contain the text you intended it to. Try printing `"äüöß".length()`. If it prints 8, then that is probably the problem.

Comment: @Abre: both of these are pointless. Apache POI doesn't write text files, so passing it a `Writer` won't work (and would be pointless if it did) and I'm pretty sure that `file.encoding` is also not involved in POI writing those files.

Comment: Cannot reproducing. Your simple example works for me using `apache poi 4.1.2`and `Java 12` on linux as well as Windows and generates a `Word` document having all the characters properly encoded in the table cell. What encoding is your `*.java` file stored on? What encoding is `javac` using while compiling? Do they match?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Yes, it actually prints 8. I still don't have an idea how to fix it.

Comment: Okay, so I've changed the Global and Project encodiong to UTF-8 via Settings->Editor->File encodings. It still printed 8 as `string.length()`.

Comment: @habrix: that means your Java source file was compiled to .class files with the wrong encoding. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726174/how-to-compile-a-java-source-file-which-is-encoded-as-utf-8) on how to fix that.

Comment: @habnix: I don't know what IDE you're talking about. This is not about the editor, but about the compiler.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ, haven't been able to solve the issue using the link either, even with using the project's path and setting the encoding to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set your file encodings to `UTF-8` in IntelliJ. If you didn't have UTF-8 set in IntelliJ before, you might have to recreate the .java file, which contains the code you show in your question (a restart of the IDE would probably also be a good idea), as changed encoding settings are effective for new files only.

And if you are using `gradle`, add this line to your `build.gradle`:

```
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006974119-File-encoding-ignored-by-compiler