# Java Swing not showing emoticons correctly after building

Tags: java

My Java Application contains Label which shows emoticons and Textfields which shows some information in other language i.e Hindi
When i run it from my IDE (Netbeans) it shows emoticons , Text in Textfields correctly
[image: Application Run from IDE]

But when i build it and run directly from .JAR it shows some characters like this

[image: Application Built]

I have already set the font but it works only with IDE but not after building.
Textfield also shows the same unrecognizable character same as the above label **Made With BY DEMO**

Comment: @camickr how can i check that out?

Comment: Edit your question and show the code which generates the text for the “Made With” component.  I suspect you are creating a String from bytes without specifying a charset.

Comment: @VGR I'm directly setting text for label from properties tab. as the answer below mention about using UTF-8 . is there a way i can set it for the whole application while building it.

Comment: That answer merely works around what is likely a mistake in your code.  Is there not a .java file that calls the `setText` method of your JLabel?

Comment: @VGR it have a java file. i got your point that i need to set charset for the label. as i'm a beginner i don't know how to do that. here's the code - `jlabel1.setText("Made With By DEMO");`

Comment: Can I assume you meant to write `jlabel1.setText("Made With ♥ By DEMO");`?

Comment: @VGR yes thats correct

Comment: The proper fix is to make sure your source file is interpreted correctly at compile time.  If you compile on the command line, use `-encoding UTF-8`.  For example:  `javac -encoding UTF-8 Developer.java`  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726174/how-to-compile-a-java-source-file-which-is-encoded-as-utf-8.  Once the class is compiled, the String constants in the compiled .class file are correct no matter how or where they’re run, since a Java runtime always interprets them in the same way.

Comment: @VGR Thanks alot i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try file.encoding option, while running the jar file.

```
java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar MyApplication.jar
```