# How to put Unicode char in Java String?

Tags: java, string, unicode, char

How to put Unicode char U+1F604 in Java String?
I attempted using

```java
String s = "\u1F604";
```

but it equivalent to

```java
String s = "\u1F60"+"4";
```

it was split into 2 chars.

Comment: There are several existing questions on SO which address you concern. As well as the linked duplicate, some answers to the question [Manually converting unicode codepoints into UTF-8 and UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6240055/2985643) provide very helpful explanations of how encoding to UTF-8 and UTF-16 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UTF-16 encoding of your character `U+1F604` is `0xD83D 0xDE04`, so it should be:

```
String s = "\uD83D\uDE04";
```

Comment: This is not a good answer for several reasons: [1] You haven't explained or shown how to determine the UTF-16 encoding from the code point. You've just presented it as a _fait accompli_. [2] This is not a general solution. You have hard-coded the solution for that specific codepoint only. [3] Since Java 11 there is a better and simpler approach, as shown in the answer from [Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68258582/2985643), which can easily be tweaked to work for any codepoint in any plane.

Answer (score 10):

DuncG's answer is a good way of doing it. The short explanation for this is that Unicode characters, by default, only take up 4 bytes, so the string literal escape only allows `\u####`. However, emojis are [surrogate pairs](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2274038&seqNum=10) and Unicode has reserved `U+D800` to `U+DFFF` for these pairs, allowing 1024 x 1024 pair characters.

A different way of doing it that doesn't require converting into UTF-16 and encoding as a surrogate pair is to use `Character.toChars(...)`:

```java
public class Main {
	public static void main(String[] args) {
		String s = "Hello " + new String(Character.toChars(0x1f604)) + "!";
		System.out.println(s);
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxD4IwFIRn@BXPTm2MBBPjYpxcXJwcjcMTKoKlJX0P1Bh@ey3B6S733V2DA65cp21TPkPo@pupCygMEsEJawvfNPmHxMhRBleX0EYkz@xrW12ugL4iNTWTOQKCPYijNsaBgCVY/YKZyMMDPRasfcZu8iTz9/q@zTdKxaJYiN308iHWbeZ6zrq4YmMlqQjGdAzhBw)

Answer (score 7):

The third variant, especially [`Character.toString(0x1f604)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)):

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Hello " + Character.toString(0x1f604) + "!"; // Since Java 11
    String s2 = "Hello " + new String(new int[]{0x1f604}, 0, 1) + "!"; // < 11
    System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
  }
}
```

(Notice that in some *other* languages `\U0001f604` might be used. In java `\u` and `\U` are the same.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this UTF-16 [*smiley face*](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F604/) symbol to the string as a *symbol* itself, as a hexadecimal or decimal *surrogate pair*, or its supplementary *code point*.

```java
// symbol itself
String str1 = "";
// surrogate pair
String str2 = "\uD83D\uDE04";
// surrogate pair to its supplementary code point value
int cp = Character.toCodePoint('\uD83D', (char) 0xDE04);
// since 11 - decimal codepoint to string
String str3 = Character.toString(cp);
// since 11 - hexadecimal codepoint to string
String str4 = Character.toString(0x1f604);

// output
System.out.println(str1 + " " + str2 + " " + str3 + " " + str4);
```

Output:

Comment: But if you do this I think you have to compile it with a command line flag, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25541706/751579

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string representation of a *hexadecimal* value of a character, you can read a numeric value using [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) method.

```java
// surrogate pair
char high = (char) Integer.parseInt("D83D", 16);
char low = (char) Integer.parseInt("DE04", 16);
String str1 = new String(new char[]{high, low});

// supplementary code point
int cp = Integer.parseInt("1F604", 16);
char[] chars = Character.toChars(cp);
String str2 = new String(chars);

// since 11
String str3 = Character.toString(cp);

// output
System.out.println(str1 + " " + str2 + " " + str3);
```

Output: